# Proof of Existence of a Composition Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Could someone please explain, in detail, the section of the proof involving the projection map? The rest of the proof I am OK with, but I am struggling to understand why $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is used, rather than $G_{i+1}/G_i$ and why the inverse of $H$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$ and $G_i$ is normal in $H$.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a typo. After all, they are trying to show $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple, and they have $\pi^{-1}(H) \subseteq G_{i+1}$, so the projection map is likely $\pi:G_{i+1}\to G_{i+1}/G_i$.

Comment: You have stated the theorem wrong. You mean a chain of subgroups, not a chain of normal subgroups.

Comment: It came from a set of online notes http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/594/JordanHolder.pdf. I would like some clarification though on the points I have specified regarding the mapping.

Comment: @wrb98 The inverse image of a normal subgroup under a group homomorphism is a normal subgroup: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normality_satisfies_inverse_image_condition. This, along with the changes Derek Holt and I noted, clear up the proof.

Comment: The proof should also say "let $H$ be a *nontrivial* normal subgroup of G_{i+1}/G_i," and should argue that $\pi^{-1}(H)$ is not equal to $G_i$ or $G_{i+1}$.

Comment: Could you provide a correct version of the proof?

Comment: As I said before the statement of the theorem is wrong, so there is no possibility of providing a correct version of the proof, because you cannot prove a false result. The statement in false in $A_4$ for example.

Comment: Clearly, there is a typo in the original document. As I have said before, this is not my fault as I have not produced the document (so why this deserves a is in an earlier comment, so obviously that is the theorem I am referring to when I ask for a proof, not the incorrect version.

Comment: @kccu That's great for the first point, but why is $G_i$ normal in $H$? Also, how would one show that the inverse is not equal to $G_{i}$ or $G_{i+1}$?

Comment: But what you have written is wrong, and that is your fault. So you should correct it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @wrb98 The $G_i$ do not have to be normal in $G$, only in $G_{i+1}$. I think this is what Derek Holt is referring to. $G_i$ is normal in $\pi^{-1}(H)$ because it is normal in $G_{i+1}$ and $\pi^{-1}(H)\subseteq G_{i+1}$. $\pi^{-1}(H)$ cannot be $G_i$ or $G_{i+1}$ because $H=\pi^{-1}(H)/G_{i+1}$ is nontrivial in $G_i/G_{i+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that the $G_i$ do not have to be normal in $G$, but I do not understand what Derek Holt is referring to, because I never mentioned that this were the case. The error lies in the screenshot I took of math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/594/JordanHolder.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose $r$ is the maximal such that exists $$0=G_0\subset G_1\cdots \subset G_r=G$$, and suppose $H\triangleleft G_{i+1}/G_i$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup. denote $\pi :G_{i+1}\rightarrow G_{i+1}/G_i$ be the quotient map.
then $H^\prime =\pi ^{-1}(H)$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$, since if $h\in H^\prime$ and $g\in G_{i+1}$ then $\pi(g^{-1}hg)=\pi(g)^{-1}\pi(h)\pi(g)\in H$ because $\pi(g)\in G_{i+1}/G_i$ and $H$ is normal in $G_{i+1}/G_i$. so $$g^{-1}hg=\pi^{-1}(h^\prime)$$ for some $h^\prime \in H$, and therefore $g^{-1}hg\in H^\prime$ so $H^\prime$ is normal.

on the other hand it is obvious that $G_i\subseteq H^\prime\subseteq G_{i+1}$. 
if $H^\prime=G_i$ then $H=\pi(H^\prime)=G_{i+1}/G_i$ in contradiction, and similarly if $H^\prime=G_{i+1}$ then $H={0}$ by contradiction.

finally $G_i\triangleleft H^\prime$, since $G_i\triangleleft G_{i+1}$.

so we got that $0=G_0\subset G_1\subset\cdots \subset G_{i}\subset H^\prime\subset G_{i+1}\subset \cdots \subset G_r=G$ is a normal sequence of length $r+1$.